# Manipulating a list

Tags: r, list

I have this shortened list here:

```
> dput(head(included_words, 100))
list(c(1L, 1L), 1:2, c(1L, 3L), c(1L, 4L), c(1L, 6L), c(1L, 7L
), c(1L, 8L), c(1L, 10L), c(1L, 12L), c(1L, 13L), c(1L, 14L), 
    c(1L, 16L), c(1L, 17L), c(1L, 19L), c(1L, 22L), c(1L, 25L
    ), c(1L, 26L), c(1L, 28L), c(1L, 29L), c(1L, 30L), c(1L, 
    31L), c(1L, 32L), c(1L, 34L), c(1L, 35L), c(1L, 37L), c(1L, 
    38L), c(1L, 39L), c(1L, 40L), c(1L, 41L), c(1L, 42L), c(1L, 
    44L), c(1L, 49L), c(1L, 50L), c(1L, 55L), c(1L, 57L), c(1L, 
    59L), c(1L, 60L), c(1L, 63L), c(1L, 65L), c(1L, 67L), c(1L, 
    68L), c(1L, 69L), c(1L, 70L), c(1L, 71L), c(1L, 72L), c(1L, 
    73L), c(1L, 74L), c(1L, 75L), c(1L, 76L), c(1L, 77L), c(1L, 
    78L), c(1L, 79L), c(1L, 80L), c(1L, 81L), c(1L, 82L), c(1L, 
    83L), c(1L, 84L), c(1L, 85L), c(1L, 86L), c(1L, 88L), c(1L, 
    89L), c(1L, 90L), c(1L, 91L), c(1L, 92L), c(1L, 93L), c(1L, 
    94L), c(1L, 95L), c(1L, 96L), c(1L, 97L), c(1L, 98L), c(1L, 
    100L), c(1L, 103L), c(1L, 105L), c(1L, 108L), c(1L, 109L), 
    c(1L, 110L), c(1L, 111L), c(1L, 113L), c(1L, 114L), c(1L, 
    115L), c(1L, 116L), c(1L, 118L), c(1L, 119L), c(1L, 120L), 
    c(1L, 121L), c(1L, 122L), c(1L, 124L), c(1L, 127L), c(1L, 
    128L), c(1L, 129L), c(1L, 130L), c(1L, 131L), c(1L, 132L), 
    c(1L, 133L), c(1L, 134L), c(2L, 1L), c(2L, 2L), c(2L, 4L), 
    c(2L, 5L), c(2L, 7L))
```

What I would like to do is to pull out all the components with 1 as the first value---- For example, ( 1 2 ), (1 3), (1 5), etc 
and then put all the second values (2, 3, 5) into the first component, pull out all the components with 2 as the first value and put all the second values into the second component, etc.

Here's what I have so far:

```
lapply(1:length(included_words), function(x) test[[x]][2], test = included_words)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with `split`. Here it is with the tidyverse approach.

```
library(tidyverse)

included_words %>%
  map(~data.frame(x=.[1], y = .[2])) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  split(.$x) %>%
  map(~(.$y))

# $`1`
#  [1]   1   2   3   4   6   7   8  10  12  13  14  16  17  19  22  25  26  28  29  30  31
# [22]  32  34  35  37  38  39  40  41  42  44  49  50  55  57  59  60  63  65  67  68  69
# [43]  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  88  89  90  91
# [64]  92  93  94  95  96  97  98 100 103 105 108 109 110 111 113 114 115 116 118 119 120
# [85] 121 122 124 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134

# $`2`
# [1] 1 2 4 5 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to work with this is to turn it into a dataframe:

```
word_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, included_words))
```

Once that's done, you have multiple options.  To create your list by the first (column), I find the `plyr` package easiest:

```
library(plyr)
dlply(word_df, .(V1), function(x) x$V2)
```

Note that while the `plyr` package is intuitive and a great tool for data manipulation, it's no longer being actively developed.  It's being replaced with packages `purrr` and `dplyr`.

Using the `dplyr` package, you'd start with something like

```
library(dplyr)
grouped_df <- word_df %>%
  group_by(V1)
```

Using this route, you'd probably continue chaining additional analyses/data manipulation steps to the current step, and these will be applied separately to the subset of the data frame with each value of `V1`.

Answer (score 0):

If we are using `base R`, then

```
with(setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, included_words),
    c("V1", "V2")), split(V2, V1))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution:

```
mat <- matrix(unlist(included_words),2)
tapply(mat[2,],mat[1,],identity)

# $`1`
# [1]   1   2   3   4   6   7   8  10  12  13  14  16  17  19  22  25  26  28  29  30  31  32  34  35  37  38  39  40  41  42  44  49
# [33]  50  55  57  59  60  63  65  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  88  89  90  91  92
# [65]  93  94  95  96  97  98 100 103 105 108 109 110 111 113 114 115 116 118 119 120 121 122 124 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 1 2 4 5 7
```